# How to change permissions with google script for multiple files and users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a master spreadheet that contains ids of other spreadsheets, also it contains different emails and permission roles that should be granted to those emails, and taken away in some point of time. Checked checkbox is the triger to remove access.

I have created a sample in 2022 that looks like this
[image: sample]

It has the script that grants the access, at least it used to back in 2022. But now when I opened it in 2023 to write 'removing access' script, it's no longer working.

```
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const fileId = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
  const emailAndPermissions = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

  for (i = 0; i < fileId.length; i++) {

    var fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId[i]);

    if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Commenter") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }
    else if (emailAndPermissions[i][1] === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(emailAndPermissions[i][0]);
    }

  }
}
```

Can someone help me fix it so it can give and remove access?
Also if you know how to put the dates of those actions on the right. it would be just amazing!

here is the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z81h6f4zitqMUb2enho_lZpmQlrO92MGxaLRpoXNFeg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `'removing access' script` and your showing script. From `Checked checkbox is the triger to remove access.` and `at least it used to back in 2022.`, it seems that your showing script doesn't include the script for `'removing access' script`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? And, can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Current issue: this code is absolutely useless :(
It was working in 2022, but not anymore. I need it to be fixed.
My script doesn't remove access. But I want him to do it when the checkbox is checked (value = true).

Comment: Just run the code, but it didn't work. Any access wasn't given and any access was taken away

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Just run the code, but it didn't work. Any access wasn't given and any access was taken away`, I apolorize for this. I have already updated my answer. Please test it again. Because, I had thouoght that when the checkbox is checked, you wanted to add the permission. But, I noticed that my understanding was the opposite. So, I updated it. In the updated script, when the checkbox is checked, the permission is removed.

Comment: In the 1st sample script, when the checkbox is checked, the permission is removed by the current value of the rule. But, when the checkbox is checked, if you want to remove the permission of the email without being related to the rule, please test the added script.

Comment: Yes, it totally works! Thank you a lot, you are the magician! =)

Comment: by the way, is it possible that removing access is triggered by the fixed time after the user was granted the access?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Yes, it totally works! Thank you a lot, you are the magician! =)`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: About your new question of `by the way, is it possible that removing access is triggered by the fixed time after the user was granted the access?`, when you want to give the expiration time for the permission. When Drive API is used, this can be achieved. You can see the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions). Please check `expirationTime`. Or, I think that if you cannot use Drive API, how about running the script for removing the permission with the time-driven trigger? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

In the current stage, for example, when there is a Spreadsheet shared with user "A", when the permission of user "B" is tried to remove, an error occurs. Because the user "B" is not shared. In this case, it is required to check whether user "B" is included in the shared users. But, from your situation, in this case, when "try-catch" is used, this process might be able to be removed. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for using "try-catch" for checking whether the user is included in the shared users.

#### Sample script:

```js
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    .forEach(([fileId, email, role, check]) => {
      if (fileId && email && role) {
        try {
          DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)[`${check === false ? "add" : "remove"}${role}`](email);
        } catch (e) {
          // console.log(e.message); // You can see the error message when you use this.
        }
      }
    });

  // The following comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
  // So, please don't remove the following comment line.
  // DriveApp.createFile();
}
```

- In your sample Spreadsheet, the values of the role are `Viewer`, `Commenter`, and `Editor`. So I directly used these values in this script. If you change the values of the dropdown list, please modify the above script. Please be careful about this.
- In this sample, the users are added and removed using the values of column `Triger "true" to remove`. For example, when the values of `Role` and `Triger "true" to remove` are "Viewer" and the unchecked checkbox, the email is added as "Viewer". And, when the values of `Role` and `Triger "true" to remove` are "Viewer" and the checked checkbox, the email is removed from "Viewer". Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [addViewer(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addViewer(String))
- [addCommenter(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addcommenteremailaddress)
- [addEditor(emailAddress)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoremailaddress)

### Added:

In the above script, when the checkbox is checked, the permission is removed by the current value of the rule. But, when the checkbox is checked, you want to remove the permission of the email without being related to the rule, please test the following script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function shareFile2() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange("A2:D" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
    .forEach(([fileId, email, role, check]) => {
      if (fileId && email && role) {
        try {
          const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
          if (check === false) {
            file[`add${role}`](email);
          } else {
            const userList = [file.getViewers().map(e => e.getEmail()), file.getEditors().map(e => e.getEmail())];
            const f = userList[0].includes(email) ? "removeViewer" : userList[1].includes(email) ? "removeEditor" : "";
            if (f) {
              file[f](email);
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      }
    });

  // DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addViewer
  // The following comment line is used for automativally detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
  // So, please dont't remove the following comment line.
  // DriveApp.createFile();
}
```